# Append duplicates and then triples the previously deleted list

Tags: python, list, sorting, append

I first populate the list and then save it in another one, then populate and save it again, but it comes duplicated with what it already has and the first time I populate it with data it's gone

This is my code:

```
import random

students = ['Talles','Emanuel','TheusDido','Bianca','Ivan','Jão']
sorteds = []
raffled = ''
double = []
i = 0

while len(students) != 0:
    raffled = random.choice(students)
    students.remove(drawn)
    duo.append(drawn)
    i += 1
 
    if(i == 2):
        sorteds.append(double)
        i = 0
        double.clear()
print(sorteds)
```

Expected result:

```
 [['Theusdido','Talles'],['Ivan','Bianca'],['Jão','Emanuel']
```

Result happened:

```
 [[],[],[]]
```

Comment: What is `drawn` and `duo`?

Answer (score 0):

This resolve all:

```
 if(i == 2):
    sorteds.append(double.copy())
    i = 0
    double.clear()
```

When i do this "sorteds.append(double)" i am making a pointer, and will always be the same in relation to the data, but when I put ".copy()" in the list, it only copies the values, not the place in memory

Comment: You could also `double = []` again, instead of using `.clear()`. That creates a new list, thus a new reference ("pointer") and you don't need to `.copy()`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the assumption that you want to draw random pairs of students, this can be done by [shuffling](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) and then [slicing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) the list of students into pairs (or any other sample size). Doing this in a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-list-comprehension) allows you to make it a list of pairs (as you expect) in one go. Example:

```
import random

students = ['Talles','Emanuel','TheusDido','Bianca','Ivan','Jão']

# This shuffles the list in-place:
random.shuffle(students)
    
# This slices and creates a list of pairs in one go:
pairs = [students[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(students), 2)]

# This is the same, without list comprehension:
pairs = []
for i in range(0, len(students), 2):
  pairs.append(students[i:i+2])

# Result: [['TheusDido', 'Jão'], ['Bianca', 'Ivan'], ['Emanuel', 'Talles']]
```

Note: If you have e. g. 5 or 7 students, the last one in the shuffled list will be solo, like so: `[['Talles', 'Ivan'], ['Emanuel', 'Bianca'], ['TheusDido']]` Sorry Jão, you're out.

Note 2: Replace both `2` with `3` and you get groups of three: `[['TheusDido', 'Jão', 'Bianca'], ['Ivan', 'Emanuel', 'Talles']]`